# How to Refresh WebPage using accelerometer values

Tags: android, accelerometer

I have created application with accelerometer values. i want to refresh the webpage using the accelerometer Values (X,Y,Z).

Notes:
   I having one webpage named index.html in that while clicking on the button i can reload the page.. using `window.location.reload()`

but i want to reload index.html page using accelerometer  values. i had a application getting accelerometer values..

how can i identify pro-grammatically, the device is shaken..

Comment: you need to be more specific. What webpage?

Comment: Could you be more specific? How would you like to refresh what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the full example on the [Accleration doc page](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.8.0/cordova_accelerometer_accelerometer.md.html#accelerometer.watchAcceleration). In the onSuccess method of watchAcceleration you can update your web page. I would not tell it to reload as that would stop all the JS running on the page and cause PhoneGap, etc. to get reloaded.

Comment: i did't used phonegap i just created application like phonegap. i get the accelerator values from that..

Comment: Then why did you add the PhoneGap tag? You need to be more specific when asking a question.